# ssh Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive)

Tags: ssh

I'm going mad. Please help me.

I have been trying to ssh to my pi. I connected it to my macbook via ethernet cable. But when I type ssh pi@, it requires password. I typed 'raspberry' and the it requires again its password. again and again. what is the problem?

I changed the password to 'pi' and tried same thing. It didn't work.

With a monitor I turned on the pi locally and typed ssh pi@localhost and it worked perfectly.

Would you please tell me how to ssh?

Comment: use `ssh -v pi@X.X.X.X`, make sure you're connecting to right place (IP), also did you made any configuration change to `sshd` or `pam`?

Comment: no, not at all. Now I found that from some PC I can ssh into the raspberry pi. But from some PCs I can't. I have no idea what happened... Recently I formatted the Pi and have not changed any configuration. Since I didn't try ssh before formatting, I can't say the difference.

Comment: @Nownuri And you're sure you're connecting to the right IP and have SSH enabled on the Pi? I once had an issue similar to this until I realized that I had accidentally been trying to SSH into my desktop because the network had changed the IP addresses around.